# QuickBlox Attachment issue in Android

Tags: android, quickblox

In group chat I am attaching single file, while sending the QBMessage object has on 1 attachment but on receive that QBMessage object the same attachment comes twice.

This happens only in group chat. In private chat it works properly

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using samples from here as a starting point for your application: https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk 
I had the same bug with it, so my quick solution was override sendMessage method in [GroupChatImpl.java](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/blob/master/sample-chat/src/main/java/com/quickblox/sample/chat/utils/chat/GroupChatImpl.java)

```
@Override
public void sendMessage(QBChatMessage message) throws XMPPException, SmackException.NotConnectedException {
    if (qbChat != null) {
        try {
            qbChat.sendMessageWithoutJoin(message);
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException | IllegalStateException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already overridden the same method still facing this issue.